# Angularjs - Why mock $httpBackend and not $http

Tags: angularjs

The Angularjs tutorial shows something using the $http service and then testing that using the $httpBackend mock. What it doesn't explain is why you mock $httpBackend and not just mock the $http service itself?  Can anyone shed light of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mock `$httpBackend`. You use it to mock the actual HTTP requests that `$http` makes. I suppose you probably could just mock `$http` itself, but `$httpBacked` provides a lot of functionality for asserting certain requests are made (The `expect` methods) and for just dummying in a response (The `when` methods). In short, `$httpBacked` makes testing code that uses `$http` much much easier.

Comment: I guess it just doesn't explain it well in the docs. Usually (from what I gather) you service A and in testing you provide a mock A which gets injected instead.  However here with have service H and the mock library provides a mock Hbackend to inject.  Does the real $http use a real $httpBackend usually, but instead gets the mock $httpBackend, or is $httpBackend just a mock $http in which case how does angular know that is the case?

Comment: The way I understand it, `$http` does use an `$httpBackend` service, and then when using the `ngMock` module for tests, angular provides a different implementation of `$httpBackend` that allows you to test functionality making HTTP requests.

Comment: Also, one of the biggest advantages of using `$httpBackend` over `$http` is the fact that you don't need to wait for a-sync call to a server, it works synchronously, check this reading: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend